# How to use custom UserProvider or maybe it must be AuthenticatedProvider?

Tags: symfony

I need to request user info from URFAClient (NetUP UTM5 billing system), but custom UserProvider's docs says that i need load user bu username without password.

I can't do this, because all request to URFAClient must contain both username and password, i can't load userinfo without password.

I totally confiused about how to add my very custom UserProvider, and docs says nothing about what i need.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

It will explain you how to implement your own firewall / UserProvider if you need an user without password